# VB.NET Return Form Object using Form Name

Tags: vb.net

I'm basically writing a custom Error Logging Form for one of my applications because users cannot be trusted to report the errors to me.

I am obtaining the Form Name using the 'MethodBase' Object and then getting the DeclaringType Name.

```
    Dim st As StackTrace = New StackTrace()
    Dim sf As StackFrame = st.GetFrame(1)
    Dim mb As MethodBase = sf.GetMethod()
    Dim dt As String = mb.DeclaringType.Name
```

How can I then use this to obtain the Form Object so I can pass this to my 'screenshot method' that screenshots the particular form referenced.

```
Public Sub SaveAsImage(frm As Form)

    'Dim fileName As String = "sth.png"
    'define fileName

    Dim format As ImageFormat = ImageFormat.Png
    Dim image = New Bitmap(frm.Width, frm.Height)
    Using g As Graphics = Graphics.FromImage(image)
        g.CopyFromScreen(frm.Location, New Point(0, 0), frm.Size)
    End Using
    image.Save(_LogPath & Date.Now.ToString("ddMMyyyy") & ".png", format)

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I posted the same solution to a similar question. Try this:

`Dim frm = Application.OpenForms.Item(dt)`